# Column.setFilterBy() and Column.setSortBy() what type of parameter should i give?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, el, dynamically-generated

i'm trying to set the filtering and sorting for a column of my datatable dynamically from a managed bean, but i had a problem regarding the value that i should give to those methods, here is the code i tried :

```
  /*this is the XHTML that i try to do in Java code :
    <p:column style="text-align:center;"
     width="10"
     id="etatCol"
     filterBy="#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}"
     filterOptions="#{examenListBean.etatExamOptions}"  
     filterMatchMode="exact"
     headerText="Etat"
     filterStyle="dispo"
     sortBy="#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}" 
     rendered="true"> 

     <p:graphicImage value="/images/study_State_icons/#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}.png"/>
     </p:column>
    */

    //Patstate
    Column patSate = (Column) application.createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    patSate.setHeaderText("Etat");
    patSate.setWidth("10");
    patSate.setId("etatCol");
    patSate.setFilterBy("#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}");
    patSate.setFilterOptions(etatExamOptions);
    patSate.setFilterMatchMode("exact");
    patSate.setFilterStyle("dispo");
    patSate.setSortBy("#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}");
    patSate.setRendered(true);

    GraphicImage patsategraph = (GraphicImage) application.createComponent(GraphicImage.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    ValueExpression patsategraphExp = ef.createValueExpression(elc, "/images/study_State_icons/#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}.png", Object.class);
    patsategraph.setValueExpression("value", patsategraphExp);
    patSate.getChildren().add(patsategraph);
    table.getChildren().add(patSate);
```

everything is rendered well except the column filter,it  won't show a list of options that i provide :

```
etatExamOptions = createFilterOptions();

private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions() {

    SelectItem[] options = new SelectItem[10];

    options[0] = new SelectItem("", "X0");
    options[1] = new SelectItem(0, "X1");
    options[2] = new SelectItem(1, "X2");
    options[3] = new SelectItem(2, "X3");
    options[4] = new SelectItem(3, "X4");
    options[5] = new SelectItem(4, "X5");
    options[6] = new SelectItem(5, "X6");
    options[7] = new SelectItem(6, "X7");
    options[8] = new SelectItem(7, "X8");
    options[9] = new SelectItem(8, "X9");

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XHTML example is invalid:

```
<p:column 
  filterBy="#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}"
  sortBy="#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}" 
>
```

The [`filterBy`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf) must represent the sole property name. The same applies to [`sortBy`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSorting.jsf).

This is valid XHTML:

```
<p:column 
  filterBy="studyPatientState"
  sortBy="studyPatientState" 
>
```

Just do the same in Java code:

```
patSate.setFilterBy("studyPatientState");
patSate.setSortBy("studyPatientState");
```

In the future, try to get the XHTML working and valid first, then translate exactly that XHTML to Java code. There's **nothing** which can't be done in XHTML but only in Java.

Comment: i get this error : Failed to parse the expression [#{exam.ValueExpression[#{exam.examen.studyPatientState}]}]

Comment: I never really used PrimeFaces sorting/filtering, but this suggests that the XHTML variant as indicated in your comments actually also wouldn't have worked at all. Or does it?

Comment: Indeed, according to the PrimeFaces showcase examples, those have to represent the sole property name, not an EL value expression. I updated the answer.

Comment: this is working like a charm, BalusC the magnificent, your help is just beyond Appreciation.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for 4 days.  Couldn't figure out how the setSortBy method worked.  Gave up and tried using 'setValueExpression' instead and failed miserably.  I eventually came across this, which works perfectly.  Thank you!!!!