# How to set <p:column filterOptions> programmatically

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, dynamically-generated

Using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 4.0.

Basically, I'm trying to set a select options (dropdown) as a filter for a `<p:column>` in `<p:dataTable>` programmatically. The problem is when I set it using the code below, it renders only a simple input text although it does fire the client side filtering action. How do I get the dropdown to show?

Code of populating the list of options.

```
private SelectItem[] createFilterOptions() {

    List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    options.add(new SelectItem("", "Tout"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(0, "Pas encore"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(1, "Patient en retard"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(2, "Patient arrivé"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(3, "Trop attendu"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(4, "Patient préparé"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(5, "Examen en cours"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(6, "Examen terminé"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(7, "Résultats remis"));
    options.add(new SelectItem(8, "Examen annulé"));

    return options;
}
```

This is how I set the value of column's filterOptions property:

```
SelectItem[] etatExamOptions = createFilterOptions();
Column patSate = (Column) application.createComponent(Column.COMPONENT_TYPE);
patSate.setHeaderText("Etat");
patSate.setWidth("10");
patSate.setId("etatCol");
patSate.setFilterBy("examen.studyPatientState");
patSate.setFilterOptions(etatExamOptions);
patSate.setFilterMatchMode("exact");
patSate.setFilterStyle("dispo");
patSate.setSortBy("examen.studyPatientState");
patSate.setRendered(true);
```

Comment: any one please ? do i have to edit something in the question text ?

Comment: Shouldn't you fix your `setFilterBy()` and `setSortBy()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000815/column-setfilterby-and-column-setsortby-what-type-of-parameter-should-i-give

Comment: i fixed it, i still can't make this one work, @BalusC you're my mentor please help.

Comment: is this some how impossible with the existing resources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I peeked around in the [`DataTableRenderer` source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0-20130705.184420-2/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java#DataTableRenderer.encodeFilter%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable,org.primefaces.component.api.UIColumn%29). It appears that it's only rendered as a dropdown list when the `filterOptions` attribute is a value expression.

```
468    if(column.getValueExpression("filterOptions") == null) {
...        // ...            
471        writer.startElement("input", null);
...        // ...            
490    }
491    else {
...        // ...            
494        writer.startElement("select", null);
...        // ...            
514    }
```

which is somewhat strange at first glance, but makes sense considering the way how `filterOptions` is usually used in the XHTML side. They could have done a better job here, e.g. `instanceof` on the evaluated value and check if it's an array or collection of `SelectItem`, but you'll have to work with what's you been provided.

You need to set it as a value expression referring a bean property instead of as a "hardcoded" `List<SelectItem>`. Create an application scoped bean class `Data` with that list as property so that it's available by `#{data.filterOptions}` and finally create a `ValueExpression` around it and set it as filter options:

```
patSate.setFilterOptions(createValueExpression("#{data.filterOptions}", List.class));
```

Comment: I tried once :
                            column.setValueExpression("setFilterOptions",filterexpress); but it didn't work now i replace "setFilterOptions" with "filteroptions" and guess what it is working perfectly, and this is great, thank you BalusC.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the filteroption in the bean an pass it from there to the xhtml

```
<p:datatable ... filtermode="#{bean.filtemode}"....
...
public class Bean{

  public getFiltermode(){
      return "filtermode";
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you implement this, why i can't just give the array of SelectedItem to the setFilterOptions() like in XHTML ?